# Leaflet Control.Layers wrong checked state

Tags: leaflet

I'm using LayerGroups and I want to be able to show/hide those groups with a [layers control](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers)

The several LayerGroups appear on the map but the associated checkbox for each one is unchecked by default, if I click once in the checkbox it behaves properly.

[Here's the project](http://fairuaweb.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/)

How can I do to make the checkboxes checked by default?

Comment: Very good that you provided a live example of your problem but could you  also please share the relevant code for prosterity?

Comment: @iH8 in the [example tutorial on Layer Groups and Layers Control](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html) it shows that the layers are added to map in the first section, but it does not explicitly state that if this is not done, then the checkboxes will be in the wrong state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly mistake, I just needed to add the layergroup to map.layers when instantiate the map and it works as expected.

Comment: can confirm this works for me too. add the layergroup instead of the layer